# When should I write a new answer instead of editing a question?

Tags: discussion, answers, suggested-edits

I strongly believe that for SO being a useful Q&A resource we need good answers. To get the best answers I would like to know when I should edit and improve an already given answer and when I should write my own answer.

Let us take an example: Lets say there already is a good answer, but I want to add some new additional context or possible some reference to the documentation or spec, where the question is actually answered (i.e. give some theoretical background). Should I edit the existing question and hence improve this answer or should I answer it on my own, using (and basically repeating) some of the code or information already provided in the other answer?

Or should I use edits just for minor things like code formatting and spelling issues?  Please note that I do not want to do a radical change like rewriting the whole answer, but instead just want to append some information.

I believe the approach to edit the existing answer is better, as we will have in the end one single good answer instead of multiple fragments scattered over several answers. However, I would like to know the opinion of the community about that.

Comment: It sounds like you should almost certainly post a new answer. Having multiple answers is no bad thing, it allows people to rate each person's contribution separately.

Comment: But in the end, do we really care about rewarding people and giving them reps? I thought it is about creating the most useful resource for programmers. I also don't think having multiple answers is bad, as there are often many possible solutions or explanations to one question.

Comment: FYI, [here's the context](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23215931/456814). Also note that both [the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23212493/456814) and my own answer went through multiple revisions over an extended period, so something that looks like it was copied from another answer may in fact be the original source.

Comment: Certainly Cupcake's answer stands on it's own. And the comment on Uri's post below sums it up pretty nicely. And if Cupcake had been sub 2k rep, and suggested an edit of that nature on the other post even the robo-approvers would have rejected it.

Comment: @OGHaza Completely unrelated, but: I doubt the robo-approvers would have rejected this. I have seen so much more obviously wrong edits which were approved, so I kind of lost my faith here.

Comment: @dirkk, haha very true, I take it back but I would have rejected it myself ;)

Answer (score 8):

I believe that editing someone else's answer should be just to clarify the original meaning of the post (fix phrasing, format code, maybe add headers), and should not change its meaning or add to it.

This goes double for editing *questions* - if you think something should be added to the post, I think the best way to do it is to communicate with the OP using comments.

I think that an additional answer (which might reference other answers to avoid big chunks of copy-paste, and to give credit where credit is due) is the best way to add to the discussion. This way each answer has its own owner, and is consistent on its own.

Comment: I think [this quote from Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/09/15.html) is highly relevant: "Want to know an easy way to earn reputation? Find a question somewhere with several good, but incomplete, answers. Steal all the answers and write one long, complete, detailed answer which is better than the incomplete ones. Sit back and earn points while people vote up your comprehensive answer." That was posted on September 15th, 2008.

Comment: @Cupcake - thanks! that's the post where he announces SO public launch, and it was a great read :-)